AZCLI download failing on mounted drives
I am trying to download a large file (>470G) from Stanford AIMI Shared Datasets which are hosted on Azure. The link provided may not be used for browser download so I'm using azcopy installed through sudo snap install azcli.
When trying to download to the home drive, the download starts but inevitably fails due to space issues. I have a mounted ssd and hdd which are 1Tb and 4Tb. I have made folders within them where my user has all permissions but the downloads fail in both drives. The errors look like:

ERR: [P#0-T#1] DOWNLOADFAILED: [source] : 000 : File Creation Error
mkdir [destination folder]/[downloaded folder]: no such file or directory

Permissions on the destination folder via ls -l shows:
drwxrwxrwx 6 [user] [user] 4096 [date] [destination folder]

I've tried manually creating the [downloaded folder] directory but the error persists for the other folders and files. On the home drive, I didn't need to create anything inside the destination folder.
Any insight would be very helpful since I really can't download the dataset on my home drive.
System information:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS


The error you're encountering suggests that azcopy is having trouble creating directories or files in your specified destination,The error you're encountering suggests that azcopy is having trouble creating directories or files in your specified destination using df -h

Got azcopy to work by removing the snap installation and installing the package through wget. There seems to be permission issues with the snap version.
wget https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
tar -xvf downloadazcopy-v10-linux
sudo rm /usr/bin/azcopy
sudo cp ./azcopy_linux_amd64_*/azcopy /usr/bin/

